# Need to save all simple products via admin or programatically

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, simple-product, save

I need to be able to re save all simple products in order to update a custom attribute via some custom code, the attribute is only updated when a product is sold or saved or an order is cancelled. The problem occurs when I make a direct injection of inventory data to update our stock levels, using Magmi for example, each simple product will then need to be manually opened and saved from the backend admin in order to update my custom attribute.

I've tried selecting all in admin, making a minor change to attributes for all products and resaving, this does not have the same effect as opening and resaving each product individually. Reindexing doesn't help either.

What I'm trying to identify is whether any backend mass action can be used to get the effect of saving all product attributes or whether there is a piece of simple code which would have the same effect?

Please note I'm not a programmer or developer, more of an admin with limited unix ability.
Thanks..